# Update a list in a JSON file with data from a text file

Tags: json, linux, shell

good afternoon, I have the following dns.json file where I pass the url in Items:

```
{
        "CallerReference": "1605534454287",
        "Aliases": {
            "Quantity": 2,
            "Items": [
                "tester1.university.com.br",
                "tester2.university.com.br",
                "tester3.university.com.br",
                "end.university.com.br"
            ]
        },
```

Then, I have a file called list.txt with the following lines:

```
tester1.university.com.br
tester2.university.com.br
tester3.university.com.br
tester4.university.com.br
tester5.university.com.br
tester6.university.com.br
tester7.university.com.br
tester8.university.com.br
```

I needed my list.txt file to be read and insert it automatically in dns.json and it looks like this:

```
{
        "CallerReference": "1605534454287",
        "Aliases": {
            "Quantity": 2,
            "Items": [
                "tester1.university.com.br",
                "tester2.university.com.br",
                "tester3.university.com.br",
                "tester4.university.com.br",
                "tester5.university.com.br",
                "tester6.university.com.br",
                "tester7.university.com.br",
                "tester8.university.com.br",
                "end.university.com.br"
            ]
        }
```

I have a lot of difficulty in shell, could you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), a tool built specifically for querying and updating JSON:

```
jq --rawfile newListStr list.txt '
  [$newListStr | split("\n")[] | select(. != "")] as $newList |
  ["end.university.com.br"] as $suffix |
  .Aliases.Items = $newList + $suffix
' <in.json >out.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s dns.json -e '
  ($json).Aliases.Items:=distinct-values(
    (
      file:read-text-lines("list.txt"),
      ($json).Aliases.Items()
    )
  )
'
```

Output:

```
{
  "CallerReference": "1605534454287",
  "Aliases": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      "tester1.university.com.br",
      "tester2.university.com.br",
      "tester3.university.com.br",
      "tester4.university.com.br",
      "tester5.university.com.br",
      "tester6.university.com.br",
      "tester7.university.com.br",
      "tester8.university.com.br",
      "end.university.com.br"
    ]
  }
}
```